# Pandas: one column divided by another results in two columns of NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dividing by a column creates a new column. I can't figure out why.

I calculate a difference in two columns like so:

```
(pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(clf.get_best_score())["validation"] - pd.DataFrame(clf.get_best_score())["learn"]))

                0
Recall         -0.050
F1             -0.766
CrossEntropy    0.006
Precision      -0.842
```

When trying to calculate this a quotient by dividing, I get the following:

```
(pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(clf.get_best_score())["validation"] - pd.DataFrame(clf.get_best_score())["learn"])) / pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(clf.get_best_score())["learn"])


                0   learn
Recall          NaN NaN
F1              NaN NaN
CrossEntropy    NaN NaN
Precision       NaN NaN
```

UPDATE:

@David
Why is it that your solution works, but when I try to specify the new column's name, `columns=["(validation - learn) / learn"]`, the result becomes NaN? See below:

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(clf.get_best_score()).iloc[:, ::-1],
           pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(clf.get_best_score())["validation"] - pd.DataFrame(clf.get_best_score())["learn"], columns = ["validation - learn"]),
           pd.DataFrame((pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(clf.get_best_score())["validation"] - pd.DataFrame(clf.get_best_score())["learn"])) / 
                        pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(clf.get_best_score())["validation"]).values
                        columns=["(validation - learn) / learn"] # specifying the new column's name here causes nans in output
                       )
          ], 
          axis = 1)
```

I get:

```
                validation  learn   validation - learn  (validation - learn) / learn
Recall          0.750      1.000    -0.250              nan
F1              0.104      1.000    -0.896              nan
CrossEntropy    0.009      0.002     0.008              nan
Precision       0.063      1.000    -0.937              nan
```

Comment: Could you copy a part of your dataset in your question?

Comment: DataFrame w/ DataFrame division aligns on **both** axes, so since the column labels are different, nothing aligns. Divide the DataFrame by the Series so alignment only occurs over the index.

Comment: try adding ".values" in the end of the command:(pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(clf.get_best_score())["validation"] - pd.DataFrame(clf.get_best_score())["learn"])) / pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(clf.get_best_score())["learn"]).values

Comment: @David I have a subsequent question about your solution, added to my post under "UPDATE."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to subtract and divide columns from 2 different dataframes. the way this is done in Pandas is based on both rows and columns indices.
adding ".values" in the end gives you the underlying numpy array, and thus the division is ignoring the index.
you are trying to create the ["(validation - learn) / learn"]

what I would to do is adding values on the "learn" column both on nominator and denominator. That should work:

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(clf.get_best_score()).iloc[:, ::-1],
           pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(clf.get_best_score())["validation"] - pd.DataFrame(clf.get_best_score())["learn"], columns = ["validation - learn"]),
           pd.DataFrame((pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(clf.get_best_score())["validation"] - pd.DataFrame(clf.get_best_score())["learn"])).values / 
                        pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(clf.get_best_score())["validation"]).values
                        columns=["(validation - learn) / learn"] # specifying the new column's name here causes nans in output
                       )
          ], 
          axis = 1)
```